# What should be the fuel mass of a hypersonic (Mach 7) rocket using APCP fuel that would deliver a 50 gram payload?

Tags: rockets, fuel, solid-fuel, rocket-equation, amateur-rocketry

Well, I used [this rocket calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/ideal-rocket-equation) besides asking [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/) and [BingGPT](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing%20AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx) and both gave me similar answers where the amount of fuel would be around 300 to 4000 grams of APCP fuel. And 30 to 100 grams for a 5 gram payload to at least 500 meters in less than a second from start point.

The rocket doesn't have guidance, no control system, the structure is supposed to be carbon fiber tube, lighter than the payload itself.

But being honest, right now I feel like that this final result isn't that great and must be wrong in some way.

It doesn't account how long it would take to accelerate to that speed (which I thought to be less than a second), nor does it take the air resistance (but I think it would be very hard to approximate an answer to that).

Comment: payload from where to where?

Comment: @AJN added it there

Comment: The rocket equation doesn't take into account air resistance or gravity losses. If you're using your payload mass as final mass, you also aren't taking into account the mass of the structure, guidance and control systems, etc. 

There are too many variables involved for a simple equation to give you an answer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I will add that information to the question, no guidance, nor control system, it lights up and that's it, the structure would be a carbon fiber tube, lighter than the payload itself.

Comment: Expecting the structure of a rocket capable of withstanding Mach 7 flight with a multiple-kg solid motor to be less than 50 g seems...optimistic. For the 4 kg propellant mass, that'd be a structural mass fraction of less than 1.25%.

Comment: "All models are wrong, some are useful."  What do you intend to use this number for?  Sometimes just a back of the envelope swag is all you need.  Other times, more detailed calculations are needed.

Comment: @CortAmmon I don't quite follow what you mean...? I mean, it is a mix of curiosity and maybe a future attempt on doing it.

Comment: The ideal rocket equation is very applicable in some regimes, and not very useful in others.  if you're just interested in a lower bound, its valid.  Otherwise other physics concerns will apply, like drag, heat, and the pressure of the propellant burning.  For instance, Christoper James Huff mentioned you're looking at a structural mass fraction of 1.25%.  The shuttle SRBs had a structural mass fraction of nearly 20%.  Depending on what you intend to do with those numbers, this might be a hard detail to ignore

Comment: Rather than asking a hallucinating AI, use some thing like https://openrocket.info/ which will give a much better idea of what you are facing. Also be aware that if truly reaching mach7 you are building a weapon so can expect additional scrutiny both in researching and in attempting to fly the thing,.

Comment: @GremlinWranger Good point. At mach 7, it's a kinetic energy weapon that's pretty close to an equal mass of gunpowder. But you'd need a license to get that much APCP anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably around in the thousand of kgs. Some quick noodling with the simulator [open rocket](https://openrocket.info/) suggests even with the highest spec tube motors you will be maxing out around mach 2, which makes sense since that is around the speed [high performance hobby rocket builders](https://www.nar.org/high-power-rocketry-info/) target as [achievable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQvK8EFJQzw) but requiring skill.

Going past mach 2 gets complicated fast, and the Sprint missile system is a useful [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(missile)) as a two stage design reaching Mach 10 with a 3.5 tonne starting mass and payload of around a [hundred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W66_(nuclear_warhead)) kg. In particular note the heating issues, meaning carbon fibre is not a useful structural material. The conical design for Sprint to achieve useful propellant volume without impossible drag involves a custom motor configuration.

Scaling Sprint from 100kg payload to 100g payload for a vehicle mass of 3.5 kg gives us a lower bound but will not be achievable due to how the square cube law works. Drag relates in part to [wetted area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetted_area) which is not scaling down as fast as the volume to actually fit the propellant does. Probably anything hyper-sonic is looking at a starting mass in the 1000kg range, regardless of payload.

Comment: Note that Sprint also didn't use a typical APCP propellant, instead it apparently used some modified double-base propellant.